# Drupal 8 - find node by Uri

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm not a Drupal developer but I have to fix a website that seems to be breaking because of a node, so I'm trying to figure out which node it is and why it's causing the error. So I changed the `getRouteName` method in the `Url.php`, in the core to this:

```
  public function getRouteName() {
    if ($this->unrouted) {

        $x = Url::fromUri($this->getUri());
        dd(var_dump($x));
        die(' === THIS IS CAUSING THE ERROR');
      throw new \UnexpectedValueException('External URLs do not have an internal route name.');
    }

    return $this->routeName;
  }
```

Which gives me this:

```
object(Drupal\Core\Url)#3626 (12) { ["urlGenerator":protected]=> NULL ["urlAssembler":protected]=> NULL ["accessManager":protected]=> NULL ["routeName":protected]=> NULL ["routeParameters":protected]=> array(0) { } ["options":protected]=> array(0) { } ["external":protected]=> bool(false) ["unrouted":protected]=> bool(true) ["uri":protected]=> string(46) "base:node/2fd814b7-2c74-4aa7-8e28-95625e2f9b8c" ["internalPath":protected]=> NULL ["_serviceIds":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_entityStorages":protected]=> array(0) { } } === THIS IS CAUSING THE ERROR
```

Then I'm trying to find the node with this uuid: `2fd814b7-2c74-4aa7-8e28-95625e2f9b8c` but it doesn't exist in the database. I'm looking in the whole database to try to find it but it seems not to exist.

I'm a bit lost. Can this debug information take me to the content that is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

To get node id of current page, simply use:

```
\Drupal::request()->get('nid')
```

And, best way to debug the breaking page is to see the logs.

Comment: except he may not be on a node page.

Comment: Thanks! It's a menu that is breaking. But I'll try that. As I said I'm not a Drupal dev, I just have to fix and explain what broke